# trigger click not properly functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on project where I want a button to be clicked right after the page load. I used .trigger("click") jquery function but it is not working.

```js
$(".one_way_btn").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="one_way_btn">One Way</button>
```

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJxxxj?editors=0010) to the project

Comment: The trigger in your project is *outside* of the `$(function() { ... }`, which is where you'd put anything that needs to wait for the page to load. By triggering your click before the page loads, you're trying to click a button that hasn't yet been rendered - the button does not yet exist when you're trying to trigger it.

Comment: as you can see on the link to the project, i have applied trigger("click" ) function and it is not giving the same effect as if you click the button yourself as a user

Comment: Please see the update to my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often because of latency and other issues the **js** will load before your content is actually on the page. So it is best to either put the script at the end of the page or run the script inside a document ready function like this.

```html
<button class="one_way_btn">One Way</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $(".one_way_btn").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

You can read more about [READY here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @halmos Just to elaborate a bit, the shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` is `$(function() { ... });` - you already have this in your code, you just need to move your trigger inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Call your `trigger` after the `click` event function i.e. `$(".one_way_btn").trigger("click");` after `$(".one_way_btn").click(function() {});` because you have defined logic on `click` event if you call trigger after that method, it will work as per your logic i.e. jQuery method executes on sequential order. And your `trigger` is outside `$(function() {});`

```js
var one_way_bool = true;

$(function() {

    $("#loader").hide()


    $(".one_way_btn").click(function() {
        $(".one_way_btn").css({
            "background-color": "black",
            "color": "white"
        });
        $(".round_trip_btn").css({
            "background-color": "transparent",
            "color": "black"
        });


        one_way_bool = true;

        $("#date-picker").css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "width": "200px",
            "color": "white",
            "left": "445px"
        });
        $("#from_auto").css({
            "width": "200px",
            "color": "white",
            "left": "0px"
        });
        $("#to_auto").css({
            "width": "200px",
            "color": "white",
            "left": "235px"
        });

        $("#search_btn").css({
            "left": "670px"
        });




        $(".datepicker-input").show()
        $(".daterangepicker-input").hide()
        $(".datepicker-input").empty()
        $(".daterangepicker-input").empty()
        $(".datepicker-input").each(function(i) {
            flatpickr("#" + this.id, {
                allowInput: true,
                enableTime: false,
                dateFormat: "y-m-d"
            });

        });

    });

    $(".one_way_btn").trigger("click");
    
    $(".round_trip_btn").click(function() {
        one_way_bool = false;
        $(".round_trip_btn").css({
            "background-color": "black",
            "color": "white"
        });

        //adjust positions of input and button tag
        $("#range-picker").css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "width": "390px",
            "color": "white",
            "left": "360px"
        });
        $("#from_auto").css({
            "width": "150px",
            "color": "white",
            "left": "0px"
        });
        $("#to_auto").css({
            "width": "180px",
            "color": "white",
            "left": "170px"
        });

        $("#search_btn").css({
            "left": "760px"
        });




        $(".one_way_btn").css({
            "background-color": "transparent",
            "color": "black"
        });
        $(".daterangepicker-input").attr("placeholder", "Date")
        $(".datepicker-input ").hide()
        $(".daterangepicker-input").show()
        $(".daterangepicker-input").empty()
        $(".datepicker-input").empty()
        $(".daterangepicker-input").each(function(i) {
            flatpickr("#" + this.id, {
                allowInput: true, //On or off doesn't change error
                enableTime: false,
                dateFormat: "y-m-d",
                mode: "range"
            });


        });

    });

});



var options = {
    shouldSort: true,
    threshold: 0.4,
    maxPatternLength: 32,
    keys: [{
        name: 'iata',
        weight: 0.5
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        weight: 0.3
    }, {
        name: 'city',
        weight: 0.2
    }]
};

var fuse = new Fuse(airports, options)


var ac = $('.autocomplete_from')
    .on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
    .on('focus keyup', search)
    .on('keydown', onKeyDown);

var wrap = $('<div>')
    .addClass('autocomplete-wrapper')
    .insertBefore(ac)
    .append(ac);

var list = $('<div>')
    .addClass('autocomplete-results')
    .on('click', '.autocomplete-result', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        selectIndex($(this).data('index'));
    })
    .appendTo(wrap);

$(document)
    .on('mouseover', '.autocomplete-result', function(e) {
        var index = parseInt($(this).data('index'), 10);
        if (!isNaN(index)) {
            list.attr('data-highlight', index);
        }
    })
    .on('click', clearResults);

function clearResults() {
    results = [];
    numResults = 0;
    list.empty();
}

function selectIndex(index) {

    if (results.length >= index + 1) {
        //console.log(results[index])
        ac.val(results[index].iata);
        clearResults();
    }
}

var results = [];
var numResults = 0;
var selectedIndex = -1;

function search(e) {
    if (e.which === 38 || e.which === 13 || e.which === 40) {
        return;
    }

    if (ac.val().length > 0) {
        results = _.take(fuse.search(ac.val()), 7);
        numResults = results.length;

        var divs = results.map(function(r, i) {
            return '<div class="autocomplete-result" data-index="' + i + '">' +
                '<div><b>' + r.iata + '</b> - ' + r.name + '</div>' +
                '<div class="autocomplete-location">' + r.city + ', ' + r.country + '</div>' +
                '</div>';
        });

        selectedIndex = -1;
        list.html(divs.join(''))
            .attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);

    } else {
        numResults = 0;
        list.empty();
    }
}

function onKeyDown(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 38: // up
            selectedIndex--;
            if (selectedIndex <= -1) {
                selectedIndex = -1;
            }
            list.attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);
            break;
        case 13: // enter
            selectIndex(selectedIndex);
            break;
        case 9: // enter
            selectIndex(selectedIndex);
            e.stopPropagation();
            return;
        case 40: // down
            selectedIndex++;
            if (selectedIndex >= numResults) {
                selectedIndex = numResults - 1;
            }
            list.attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);
            break;

        default:
            return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
}


var ac_to = $('.autocomplete_to') //here
    .on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
    .on('focus keyup', search_to)
    .on('keydown', onKeyDown_to);

var wrap_to = $('<div>')
    .addClass('autocomplete-wrapper')
    .insertBefore(ac_to)
    .append(ac_to);

var list_to = $('<div>')
    .addClass('autocomplete-results_to')
    .on('click', '.autocomplete-result', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        selectIndex_to($(this).data('index'));
    })
    .appendTo(wrap_to);

$(document)
    .on('mouseover', '.autocomplete-result', function(e) {
        var index = parseInt($(this).data('index'), 10);
        if (!isNaN(index)) {
            list_to.attr('data-highlight', index);
        }
    })
    .on('click', clearResults_to);

function clearResults_to() {
    results = [];
    numResults = 0;
    list_to.empty();
}

function selectIndex_to(index) { //here
    if (results.length >= index + 1) {
        ac_to.val(results[index].iata);
        clearResults_to();
    }
}

var results = [];
var numResults = 0;
var selectedIndex = -1;

function search_to(e) {
    if (e.which === 38 || e.which === 13 || e.which === 40) {
        return;
    }

    if (ac_to.val().length > 0) {
        results = _.take(fuse.search(ac_to.val()), 7);
        numResults = results.length;

        var divs = results.map(function(r, i) {
            return '<div class="autocomplete-result" data-index="' + i + '">' +
                '<div><b>' + r.iata + '</b> - ' + r.name + '</div>' +
                '<div class="autocomplete-location">' + r.city + ', ' + r.country + '</div>' +
                '</div>';
        });

        selectedIndex = -1;
        list_to.html(divs.join(''))
            .attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);

    } else {
        numResults = 0;
        list_to.empty();
    }
}

function onKeyDown_to(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 38: // up
            selectedIndex--;
            if (selectedIndex <= -1) {
                selectedIndex = -1;
            }
            list_to.attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex_to);
            break;
        case 13: // enter
            selectIndex_to(selectedIndex);
            break;
        case 9: // enter
            selectIndex_to(selectedIndex);
            e.stopPropagation();
            return;
        case 40: // down
            selectedIndex++;
            if (selectedIndex >= numResults) {
                selectedIndex = numResults - 1;
            }
            list_to.attr('data-highlight', selectIndex_to);
            break;

        default:
            return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
}


$(".autocomplete_from").click(function() {
    list_to.empty();
});
$(".autocomplete_to").click(function() {
    list.empty();

});



$("#search_btn").click(function() {
    var flight_endpoint = "https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/flights/low-fare-search?"
    var from = $(".autocomplete_from").val()
    var to = $(".autocomplete_to").val()
    var range_picker = $("#range-picker").val();
    var date_picker = $("#date-picker").val();

    //check if any of the filds are empty
    // if empty return
    if (from === "") {
        alert("Please Enter a valid departure location")
        return false;
    }
    if (to === "") {
        alert("Please Enter a valid arrival location")
        return false;
    }
    if (!one_way_bool & range_picker === "") {
        alert("Please Enter a valid date")
        return false;
    }
    if (one_way_bool & date_picker === "") {
        alert("Please Enter a valid date")
        return false;
    }


    $("#loader").show()

    $("#disp_result").empty()
    $("#main").css({
        "top": "-10px"
    })

    flight_endpoint += "origin=" + from;
    flight_endpoint += "&destination=" + to;

    if (one_way_bool) {
        flight_endpoint += "&departure_date=20" + date_picker;
    } else {
        var dep_date = range_picker.slice(0, 8)
        var ret_date = range_picker.slice(12, 20)
        flight_endpoint += "&departure_date=20" + dep_date + "&return_date=20" + ret_date;
    }

    flight_endpoint += "&number_of_results=7&apikey=zxIKGJSRUGGhUoyLQQdicvvJff5L3GPj";


    getResponse(flight_endpoint)

})




//var flight_endpoint = "https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/flights/low-fare-search?origin=IST&destination=ADD&departure_date=2018-10-15&return_date=2018-10-21&number_of_results=3&apikey=z18MY7Pcm4XtewNMVFYPXYe0cOVBc7tF"; 




function getResponse(url) {

    var settings = {
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //data = JSON.parse(data)
            $("#loader").hide()

            if (one_way_bool) {

                one_way_display(data)
            } else {
                round_trip_display(data)
            }

        },
        error: function(errormessage) {
            console.log(errormessage)
            console.log(errormessage.statusCode.statusText)
        }
    }
    console.log(url)
    jQuery.ajax(url, settings);
}



function one_way_display(data) {
    $("#main").append("<table id=\"disp_result\"></table>")
    $("#disp_result").append("<tr><th>Departure time</th><th>Arrival time</th><th>Route</th><th>Price</th><th>Remaining Seat</th></tr>")


    for (var i = 0; i <= data.results.length; i++) {
        var airport_string = ""
        var airport_arr = []
        var remaining_seat = 100;
        var price = 0;
        var depart_time = "";
        var arrival_time = "";
        depart_time = data.results[i].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].departs_at;
        d = new Date(depart_time)
        depart_time = d.toTimeString()
        data.results[i].itineraries[0].outbound.flights.forEach(function(currentvalue, index, arr) {
            airport_arr.push(currentvalue.origin.airport)
            airport_arr.push(currentvalue.destination.airport)
            airport_arr = jQuery.unique(airport_arr);
            price = data.results[i].fare.total_price;

            // update with the smallest seats available
            if (remaining_seat > currentvalue.booking_info.seats_remaining) {
                remaining_seat = currentvalue.booking_info.seats_remaining;
            }

            arrival_time = currentvalue.arrives_at;
        })
        airport_string = airport_arr.join("-");
        var d = new Date(arrival_time)
        arrival_time = d.toTimeString()
        $("#disp_result").append("<tr><td>" + depart_time + "</td><td>" + arrival_time + "</td><td>" + airport_string + "</td><td>" + price + data.currency + "<td>" + remaining_seat + "</td></tr>")
    }

}

function round_trip_display(data) {

    $("#main").append("<table id=\"disp_result\"></table>")
    $("#disp_result").append("<tr><th>Departure time(Out)</th><th>Arrival time(Out)</th><th>Departure time(in)</th><th>Arrival time(in)</th><th>Route(out)</th><th>Route(in)</th><th>Price</th><th>Remaining Seat</th></tr>")
    $("table").css({
        "width": "900px"
    })

    var d;
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.results.length; i++) {
        var airport_string_out = ""
        var airport_arr_out = []
        var remaining_seat = 100;
        var price = 0;
        var depart_time_out = "";
        var arrival_time_out = "";


        var airport_string_in = ""
        var airport_arr_in = []
        var depart_time_in = "";
        var arrival_time_in = "";


        depart_time_out = data.results[i].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].departs_at;
        d = new Date(depart_time_out)
        depart_time_out = d.toTimeString()
        data.results[i].itineraries[0].outbound.flights.forEach(function(currentvalue, index, arr) {
            airport_arr_out.push(currentvalue.origin.airport)
            airport_arr_out.push(currentvalue.destination.airport)
            airport_arr_out = jQuery.unique(airport_arr_out);
            price = data.results[i].fare.total_price;

            // update with the smallest seats available
            if (remaining_seat > currentvalue.booking_info.seats_remaining) {
                remaining_seat = currentvalue.booking_info.seats_remaining;
            }

            arrival_time_out = currentvalue.arrives_at;
        })
        airport_string_out = airport_arr_out.join("-");
        d = new Date(arrival_time_out)
        arrival_time_out = d.toTimeString()

        //inbound

        depart_time_in = data.results[i].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].departs_at;
        d = new Date(depart_time_in)
        depart_time_in = d.toTimeString()
        data.results[i].itineraries[0].inbound.flights.forEach(function(currentvalue, index, arr) {
            airport_arr_in.push(currentvalue.origin.airport)
            airport_arr_in.push(currentvalue.destination.airport)
            airport_arr_in = jQuery.unique(airport_arr_in);

            // update with the smallest seats available
            if (remaining_seat > currentvalue.booking_info.seats_remaining) {
                remaining_seat = currentvalue.booking_info.seats_remaining;
            }

            arrival_time_in = currentvalue.arrives_at;
        })
        airport_string_in = airport_arr_in.join("-");
        d = new Date(arrival_time_in)
        arrival_time_in = d.toTimeString()




        $("#disp_result").append("<tr><td>" + depart_time_out + "</td><td>" + arrival_time_out + "</td><td>" + depart_time_in + "</td><td>" + arrival_time_in + "</td><td>" + airport_string_out + "</td><td>" + airport_string_in + "</td><td>" + price + data.currency + "<td>" + remaining_seat + "</td></tr>")
    }

}
```

```css
#bio{
     min-height: 100%;
     min-width: 1024px;
    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
    /* Set up positioning */
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499561385668-5ebdb06a79bc?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1949&q=80");
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center center;
}
 #main{
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 15;
     top: 40%;
     left: 35%;
     margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
     opacity: 0.7;
}
 body {
     margin: 50px;
}
 .form-group {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
}
 .control-label {
     display: block;
}
 .autocomplete-wrapper {
     position: relative;
}
 .autocomplete-results, .autocomplete-results_to {
     position: absolute;
     background: white;
     z-index: 1;
     top: 50px;
     left: 0;
     font-size: 13px;
     border: solid 1px #ddd;
     border-top-width: 0;
     border-bottom-color: #ccc;
     box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
 .autocomplete-results_to{
     left: 234px;
     width:210px;
}
 .autocomplete-result {
     padding: 12px 15px;
     border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .autocomplete-result:last-child {
     border-bottom-width: 0;
}
 .autocomplete-location {
     opacity: .8;
     font-size: smaller;
}
 #to_auto{
     position:absolute;
     left: 235px;
     top:0px;
}
 #from_auto{
     position:absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top:0px;
}
 #date-picker{
     position:absolute;
     left: 445px;
     top:164px;
}
 #range-picker{
     position:absolute;
     left: 445px;
     top:163px;
}
 #search_btn{
     position:absolute;
     left: 670px;
     top:180px;
     width:140px;
}
 input{
     background: transparent;
     border-right-style:none;
     border-left-style:none;
     border-top-style:none;
     border-bottom-color:white;
     width:200px;
     font-size:40px;
     border-width: 4px;
     color:white;
}
 input:focus {
     outline-width: 0;
     color:white;
}
 ::placeholder {
    /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
     color: black;
     opacity: 1;
    /* Firefox */
     font-family: Papyrus, fantasy;
}
 button{
     background:transparent;
     border-color:white;
     font-size: 19px;
     color:black;
     font-family: Papyrus, fantasy;
     border-radius: 4px 
}
 button:focus {
     outline-width: 0;
}
 button:hover {
     background-color: black;
     opacity: 1;
     color:white;
}
 label{
     font-size: 30px;
     color:white;
     font-family: Papyrus, fantasy;
}
 strong{
     font-size: 100px;
}
 #disp_area{
     position:absolute;
     background-color:black;
     width: 800px;
     top: 270px;
     height: 1000px;
}
 table {
     position:absolute;
     background: black;
     border-collapse: separate;
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 24px;
     margin: 30px auto;
     text-align: left;
     width: 700px;
     top:200px;
     color:white;
}
 th {
     background: url(https://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png), linear-gradient(#777, #444);
     border-left: 1px solid #555;
     border-right: 1px solid #777;
     border-top: 1px solid #555;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #999;
     color: #fff;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 10px 15px;
     position: relative;
     text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}
 tr:nth-child(odd) td {
     background: #667182 url(https://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png);
}
 #loader{
     position:absolute;
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     left:150px;
     top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/2.6.3/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/2.6.3/flatpickr.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.1/lodash.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fuse.js@2.5.0/src/fuse.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://screenfeedcontent.blob.core.windows.net/html/airports.js"></script>





<div id="main">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Flight Search</label>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

    </div>
    <label class="control-label">Enter Your Flight details below</label>

    <br>
    <button class="one_way_btn">One Way</button>
    <button class="round_trip_btn">Round Trip</button><br>

    <input class="autocomplete_from" type="text" placeholder="From" id="from_auto" />

    <input class="autocomplete_to" type="text" id="to_auto" placeholder="To" />


    <input id="date-picker" class="datepicker-input " type="text" placeholder="Date">
    <input id="range-picker" class="daterangepicker-input" type="text">
    <button id="search_btn">Search Flights</button>
    <img src="https://www.pedul.com/images/loading.gif" id="loader">
</div>


<div id="bio"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to trigger the event before it has been declared. Try moving it to the bottom of your code.

Comment: An event listener doesn't need to be declared after its function declaration. It does however need to wait for the DOM to load before assigning itself to a node.

Comment: Ah - yes, you are correct. I ran a test with it in a document ready block.